# Expected value and variance of uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, variance, expected-value

I have to find the expected value and variance of the uniform distribution **X** that is **0** for $x<1$ and $x>3$.

Also what is the probability $P(x>1.5)$?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Typically you are more likely to get a good response if you show your effort.  This is partly so that someone answering knows where you are stuck; and partly because this isn't a site to just get homework problems answered with no effort on the part of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. The probability density function of the given continuous uniform distribution is

$$
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{2} & \mathrm{for}\ 1 \le x \le 3, \\[8pt]
  0 & \mathrm{for}\ x<1\ \mathrm{or}\ x>3,
  \end{cases}
$$ giving
$$
E(X)=\int_1^3x\cdot f(x)dx=\color{red}{?}
$$ and
$$
V(X)=\int_1^3x^2\cdot f(x)dx-\left(E(X) \right)^2=\color{red}{?}
$$
One has
$$
P(X>1.5)=\int_{1.5}^3f(x)dx=\color{red}{?}
$$

Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Can you please explain why is 1/2 for 1≤x≤3?

Comment: @jisan Sure, have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Characterization

Comment: Thanks. I understand now